# is there a better way to do this link to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

Here is my link_to

```
  <%= link_to "<input type='button', value='Somewhere', class ='big'/>".html_safe, selection_path %>
```

but in IE is not working ...its rendering

```
  <a href="/selection"><input class="big" value="Somewhere" type="button" ,=""></a>
```

so there is a breakage in the link ....any ideas on how to fix

Answer (score 6):

Use [button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) instead of putting a button inside of a link_to:

```
<%= button_to "Somewhere", selection_path, :method => :get %>
```

Comment: Right, an `<input>` inside an `<a>` isn't even valid HTML and who knows what sort of mischief a browser will get up to with such a thing.

Comment: think that's the right way to do it. Things become complicated (just a little bit) then when it comes to styling the generated form and div around the input. But the benefits overcome the pain.

Answer (score 3):

1. Shouldn't have commas between properties.
2. `link_to` is for links, `button_to` is for buttons. It's probably best to not try to mix the two. Here you've got an `input` of type `button` inside of a `link_to` helper. All kinds of confusion going on. I suppose it might work, but it seems like the hard way of doing it. Trying using a `button_to` instead

Comment: ya very true...i didnt write it...just bug fixing

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to put commas between properties.

```
<%= link_to "<input type='button' value='Somewhere' class='big'/>".html_safe, selection_path %>
```